# How to compare two comma separated string and insert in DB

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following table (Users) with 2 columns and trying to update second column with first column ( first column is  autoincrement and primary key field).

```
UserId  CatId
1         10
2         78
3         99
4         89
5         80
```

I am finding difficult to update second column with P_uid order by (1,3,4). I tried normal `Update statement` but it doesn't work. I am passing following ids into SP.

```
P_uid varchar2(20) := '1,3,4';
P_new_cat_id varchar2(20) := '100,12,13';

Expected output
---------------
UserId  CatId
1         100
2         78
3         12
4         13
5         80
```

Comment: Why are you passing strings of comma-separated values? You would have to tokenise both strings and keep the related elements in step - assuming you always have the same number of elements in both. It would be easier to pass collections, or a collection of pairs of values, or just do three separate updates. What is generating the strings and where is that data coming from?

Comment: @AlexPoole . the data coming from server side and it is dynamic. P_uid value may change

Comment: If those strings are out of your control then you will need to tokenise them somehow.

Comment: @AlexPoole I am new to Oracle. Please explain what do you mean by tokenise

Comment: Tokenise = Split them into rows where each row contains one token from each list.

Comment: @atc - what MTO showed in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO users dst
USING (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 100 AS new_catid FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 13 FROM DUAL
) src
ON (src.id = dst.userid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
    SET catid = src.new_catid;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (UserId, CatId) AS
SELECT 1, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 78 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 80 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the merge, the table contains:

> | USERID | CATID |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 100 |
> | 2 | 78 |
> | 3 | 12 |
> | 4 | 13 |
> | 5 | 80 |

---

If you have delimited strings then (apart from finding a better solution for passing multi-row data) you can split the values into rows using a row-generator function and use the previous technique:

```sql
DECLARE
  P_uid varchar2(20) := '1,3,4';
  P_new_cat_id varchar2(20) := '100,12,13';
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO users dst
  USING (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_uid,        '\d+', 1, LEVEL) AS id,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_new_cat_id, '\d+', 1, LEVEL) AS new_catid
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LEAST(
                          REGEXP_COUNT(p_uid,        '\d+'),
                          REGEXP_COUNT(p_new_cat_id, '\d+')
                        )
  ) src
  ON (src.id = dst.userid)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
      SET catid = src.new_catid;
END;
/
```

Which outputs the same.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f9dbdfc9183dca87240efdbd902987f)*

Comment: The first part is hard coded.

Comment: @atc Then split the strings into rows and use that. Updated.